# how to pick the first file first from specific folder using for each in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, bids

I have a remote folder from where i pick the multiple files and loop through for each loop container.  But I want to pick the first file first based on time stamp from that folder.
how do I do this in SSIS?

Comment: What is the version you are using?

Comment: visual studio 2013

Comment: Does Remote Folder mean FTP or just a network path? Is First the oldest create timestamp, oldest modify timestamp, oldest access timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

1. First you hace to create 2 Variables

   ```
   FolderPath (string) -- to store the folder you have to manipulate

   dtFiles (Object)   -- to store files from this folder
   ```
2. Add a script task and select FolderPath  as ReadOnlyVariable and dtFiles  as ReadWrite Variable
3. In the script write the following code

   ```
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Linq

   Public Sub Main()

   Dim strFolderPath As String = Dts.Variables.Item("FolderPath").Value.ToString

   Dim lstFiles As New List(Of IO.FileInfo)

   For Each strFile As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(strFolderPath, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

       Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(strFile)

       lstFiles.Add(fi)

   Next

   Dts.Variables.Item("dtFiles").Value = lstFiles.OrderBy(Function(x) x.CreationTime).Select(Function(x) x.FullName).ToList


   End Sub
   ```
4. Connect your script task to The For each loop Container
5. Double Click on the ForEach Loop container and change the enumerator type to ADO enumerator and choose the variable dtFiles as a source (in the collection tab) and choose the enumeration mode (Rows from first table)
6. In the variable mapping tab (in For each loop container) map the index 0 to a new Variable i.e. FileName (You can use it to do your work)

Note: i used sorted files using CreationTime. You can even use LastAccessTime and LastWriteTime properties

**Just add a value to FolderPath variable and Execute**

[image: script Task properties]

[image: For Each Loop Enumerator]

[image: For Each Loop variable mapping]

[image: Control Flow preview]